# Getting a propmt when deleteing a non-directory

Tags: directory, rm, prompt

I want to get a prompt when attempting to delete a non-empty directory with `rmdir`.  Is this possible?

Comment: `rmdir` doesn't work on non-empty directories.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get a prompt"? Do you mean that you want `rmdir` to say something like "That directory is not empty; do you want me delete all its contents?"? Or are you simply asking for a way to delete a non-empty directory (along with all its contents) without the operating system nagging you?

Answer (score 2):

@Praveen J Kumar , I'm not so clear, so I'll try to cover the basics. There are four cases here:

1. You **do** want to get prompt when deleting a directory. `-i` flag is for interactive session, and will ask you before each file is deleted. `-r` is for recursive, i.e. go over the entire directory and sub directories etc.... Then use:

   ```
   $ rm -ri <directory path>
   ```
2. You **don't** want to be prompt when deleting a directory, then use:

   ```
   $ rm -r <directory path>
   ```
3. You want to **delete only certain type of files in the directory**. For this you can use the line below where `ls -1` provide one line input, `grep -iv "jpg"` will select all of the files from `ls` output that are not `jpg` format (here `-i` flag is for case insensitive and `-v` is for anything but the "jpg" string), and `xargs rm` executes `rm` on the output of `grep`. For example, I want to remove all of the files in the directory except of `jpg`:

   ```
   $ ls -1
   one.txt
   three.jpg
   three.csv
   three.sh
   two.txt
   $ ls -1 | grep -iv "jpg" | xargs rm
   $ ls
   three.jpg
   ```
4. `rmdir` by default doesn't remove  non empty directories, so you are good :-).

Last note: when choosing `-i` flag, it can get tedious, if the directory has many files since it'll prompt you for every file.

Answer (score 1):

The `rmdir` does not provide an `-i` flag like `rm` command does when you want to confirm a deletion of a certain directory. However, `rmdir` returns an exit code of `0` when it operates on an empty directory. For example:

```
$ mkdir emptydir && rmdir emptydir && echo $?
0
```

As you can see, it does not ask us for confirmation when deleting an empty directory. The only way we can built a confirmation mechanism for `rmdir` is to write a wrapper which we call `rmemptydir`.  I've written two versions showing two different approaches.

The preferred aproach

```
#!/bin/bash

    [[ $# = 0 ]] &&  printf '%s\n' "rmdir [dirname]" exit 1
     shopt -s nullglob dotglob
    files=( ${1+"$1/"}* )
    (( ${#files[*]} )) || { rm -ri "$1" && exit 1; } && printf '%s\n' "Dir not empty" 
    shopt -u nullglob dotglob
```

1) The script accepts one parameter which is the directory name. It exits when no parameter provided

2) The positional parameter `$1` holds the directory (as array with elements)

3) The number of elements of the array is checked and if it's not `0` then go to `printf '%s\n' "Dir not empty"` else run `rm -ri "$1" && exit 1` and we are done.

The same applies to the second approach except we use `pushd` and `popd` to `push` the directory to the stack and `pop` it from the stack.

Curious how it works in the background?

Put `set -x` just under the `#!/bin/bash`  and remove `>/dev/null` after the `pushd` and `popd`

The second approach using `pushd` and `popd`

```
#!/bin/bash

 if [[ $# = 0 ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "rmdir [dirname]" 
    exit 1
 fi
 shopt -s nullglob dotglob
  pushd "$1" >/dev/null
  files=(*)
  (( ${#files[*]} )) || { popd >/dev/null && rm -ri "$1" && exit 0 ;} && printf '%s\n' "Dir not empty" 
  shopt -u nullglob dotglob
```

The following does not work since `rmdir` is able to remove empty direcotries only and we have a `music.mp3` in our directory.

```
mkdir emptydir && touch emptydir/music.mp3 && rmdir emptydir && echo $?
rmdir: failed to remove ‘emptydir’: Directory not empty
```